# Best way to include relative path with file array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, properties

I'm new to C# and need advice on how to proceed with a problem:

I'm writing code to sync folders.  To determine if two files are the same file I need to compare their relative paths (subfolders from their base directory and filename).  I've created a FileInfo array with the following code:

```
for (int y = 1; y <= nf; y++)
            {
                this.Title = "Folder Sync - Getting files from folder " + y;
                DirectoryInfo basedir = new DirectoryInfo(dirs[y]);
                dirf[y] = basedir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(item => item.FullName).ToArray();
            }
```

However, the FileInfo Class does not have a RelativePath property.  Here are options I've considered:
1.  Create a separate string array with just the relative path for each file as `file.FullName.Substring(basedir.FullName.Length)`

2. Calculate the relative path every time I need it.
3. Put both the FileInfo Objects and the RelativePath strings in an Object array
4. Extend FileInfo properties (apparently not available with current C#)
5. Create a derived class myFile info with a Relative path field/property.  Fill that in with the Relative path when making the myFileInfo array.

I just tried 5, but was running into the error "Cannot implicitly convert FileInfo[] to myFileInfo[]".  After reading up on constructors to try to fix this, I decided to take a step back and ask if this is even the right approach.

So, general question: What is the best practice way of dealing with this?
Specific question: How do I include RelativePath for each file?

Comment: Are your syncing over the network? Or are the two folders co-located on the same drive/machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd just create a new object with a FileInfo member and a string for relativepath member. I wouldn't try to derive that class from anything though, it doesn't really give you any benefits and just increases complexity.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I didn't think of using a class with a FileInfo member instead of a derived class.  That would mean that if I had an object myFileInfo file1, I would get the length as file1.FileInfo.Length instead of file1.Length, right?  What are the benefits to doing it this way?  Also, how would I use the GetFiles method to populate the myFileInfo array?

Comment: The benefits are how simple it is, composition is almost always better/simpler than inheritance. To create your list just use a linq select, and create a new object in the select statement.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm trying this method currently.

Answer (score 1):

I think 5 is pretty close to what I'd consider "standard approach".

Standard approach is to create class that represents "file" for your application and add information there. Probably that class would *contain* relative path/absolute path/base path, last modified time, hash. Avoiding direct usage of `FileInfo` would simplify unit testing of your synchronization code.

Out of other approaches you've suggested 2 (compute on demand) looks reasonable as you use `FileInfo` as source of truth.

Creating multiple parallel arrays to represent single list of objects is generally bad practice - hard to keep in sync and test.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  It's nice to know that that's the standard approach.  Are you saying I should make it a new base class instead of a derived class?  How would I use the GetFiles method to fill the myFileInfo array?

Comment: @KalevMaricq I agree with grrrrr's answer - there is no particular benefit to derive from any class based on your description. `Enumerable.Select` (LINQ) is one easy way to transform collections, but really depends on your knowledge/goals/style.